# Question about server space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, amazon-web-services

I am planning to create a webapp which user can upload mp3 files.So it required large server space.So weather I have to buy the whole server space or can i use any webservice(which giving spaces like amazon-s3).I am using Ruby on Rails .Please give me advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for something like this.

I manage a Web Service developed in Python where images are uploaded, and S3 works a treat. Needing large server space is no issue here either as I don't think there are any limits as to how much you can store on S3.

Day 1 costs $0, then you are billed monthly per byte used.

There is a tutorial for Ruby and S3 [here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/608?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1).

Comment: So that answer is appreciated.Anybody know any other services?

Comment: Mosso created cloudfs, renamed to http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/files/ ... Google's competitor is in private beta: http://code.google.com/apis/storage/

Comment: You can store as much as you want on S3 provided you pay for it, and the rate is $0.14 per GB of storage, less for higher volumes, plus a transfer fee of about $0.10 per GB sent. The first 1GB of transfer is no charge, and on the [free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) the first 5GB of storage is also no-charge.